# How to change colors in Beamer theme?

Tags: beamer

I would like to change colors in Beamer theme like Amsterdam (downloaded from the side http://latex.simon04.net the first topic). How can I get on the top instead of dark blue for example red color and instead of light blue green color? I use the headline defined like this

```
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=1.7ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{section in head/foot}
    \vskip2pt\insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{}{}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \ifbeamer@theme@subsection%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{middle separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=1.7ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{subsection in head/foot}
      \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\insertsubsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
} \mode <all>

\makeatletter
\DeclareOptionBeamer{compress}{\beamer@compresstrue}
\ProcessOptionsBeamer
```

Comment: No offense but the file is 21 lines long. And one of the lines defines the blue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
 {
 \usetheme{Amsterdam}
 \setbeamercolor*{palette secondary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=red}
 \setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=green}
 }

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}
   \lipsum
 \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Leads to:

[image]

But notice Claudio Fiandrino's comment on the other answer.

Answer (score 9):

I believe the top panel use the structure foreground color which is defined in

```
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=beamer@blendedblue}
```

where `beamer@blendedblue` is a user defined color

```
\definecolor{beamer@blendedblue}{rgb}{0.137,0.466,0.741}
```

Simple modify the RGB value to change that.  Other colors are imported from

```
\usecolortheme{whale}
\usecolortheme{orchid}
```

So you will have to override the definitions in `beamercolorthemewhale.sty` or `beamercolorthemewhale.sty` to change them.

Comment: You shouldn't touch the original themes. You can overwrite whatever setting you want to change after loading the theme.

Comment: Besides percusse comment, notice that overriding the `structure` color template, also affects all `palettes`. From that point on you should have care to redefine the proper `palette` to set it in light green as requested.