# How to change colortheme?

Tags: beamer, color

I am using theme Warsaw but I do not like the colortheme crane, how can I change the colortheme to LightCyan as in the first answer of this question?

[How do I color table columns?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94799/how-do-i-color-table-columns-and-rows)

```
\mode<presentation>
{
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{crane}
}
```

Comment: You can have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68587/how-to-change-colors-in-beamer-theme for example. You should also check section 17.1 of the beamer manual to see if another color theme would suit you without tinkering with the colors.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

simply overwrite the colours `craneorange` and `craneblue` of the colour theme by whatever you like

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme{Warsaw}
    \usecolortheme{crane}
}

\definecolor{craneorange}{rgb}{0.68,1,1}
\definecolor{craneblue}{gray}{0.85}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        test
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]